# Ansible can't connect with it's own ssh config to dynamic inventory hosts

Tags: ansible

My Ansible configuration `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
remote_user = centos
roles_path = ./roles
pipelining = True

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F /etc/ansible/ssh/ssh_config
```

`ssh_config`:

```
Host bastion.host
  Hostname bastion.host
  User centos
  IdentityFile /etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem
  StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host 10.*.*.*
  User centos
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion.host
  IdentityFile /etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

when I try to execute Ansible's playbook

```
ansible -i /etc/ansible/inventories/aws-inventory/ec2.py tag_class_master -m ping

The authenticity of host 'bastion.host' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:vwYBZHWHDXx2ehQTEhzpD4EAcTTnu5cJWsNFPOYt9Q0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'bastion.host' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:vwYBZHWHDXx2ehQTEhzpD4EAcTTnu5cJWsNFPOYt9Q0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host 'bastion.host' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:vwYBZHWHDXx2ehQTEhzpD4EAcTTnu5cJWsNFPOYt9Q0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
10.0.1.178 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.\r\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
10.0.3.188 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection timed out during banner exchange\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
10.0.2.36 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection timed out during banner exchange\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

but when I will copy my ssh_config into home directory `~/.ssh/config` it starts working. I have spent few days in debbuging it and tried different solutions like

`ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p centos@bastion.host -i /etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem"'`

in specific hosts groups. Why I need to put ssh configuration file in my home directory instead using `ssh_args = -F /etc/ansible/ssh/ssh_config` parameter? My ansible version:

```
ansible 2.5.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Ansible is docerized and I run it as root:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic-20180426

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y ansible sshpass python-pip

# install boto python module for ec2 dynamic inventory
RUN pip install boto

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

from inside my ansible repo like

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/etc/ansible/ ansible:ubuntu bash
```

Comment: `host_key_checking = False` is also ignored. Put some garbage into your `ansible.cfg` and check if Ansible reports an error, to check if Ansible uses the same file as you assume it is.

Comment: `Error reading config file (/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg): File contains no section headers.
file: /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, line: 1
'[defaults\n'`

Comment: Run `ansible` with `-vvvv` (four to print SSH trace). Add the actual `ssh` command Ansible runs to the question.

Comment: `<10.0.3.58> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos`
`<10.0.3.58> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -F /etc/ansible/ssh/ssh_config -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=centos -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.0.3.58 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''`

Comment: ...and what happens if you run this command yourself?

Comment: `10.0.3.58> (Reading configuration data /etc/ansible/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndeb: /etc/ansible/ssh/ssh_config line 7: Applying options for 10.*.*.*\r\ndebug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 10.0.3.58:22 bastion.host\r\n\ndeb: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem-cert type -1\r\n\r\nroot@bastion.host: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r')`

Comment: It looks like it's trying to connect as root `root@bastion.host: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)` instead as `centos` user which is set in `ansible.cfg` `remote_user = centos` and in `ss_config` file `User centos`

Comment: maybe I should create github issue with this?

Comment: it looks like it doesn't respect bastion.host configuration from `ssh_config`. When I add `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p centos@<external_ip> -i /etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem` for `10.*.*.*` subnet it looks it's working

Comment: you could test the config file `ssh -F /etc/ansible/ssh/ssh_config 10.0.3.88` if you suspect that ansible is only looking at the default config then you could edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to `Include` the ansible ssh config file

Comment: actually - it looks like ansible user gets permission denied on `/etc/ansible/ssh/KEY.pem` if you run with sudo is it the same?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same situation as you. I ran Ansible with -vvvv for SSH debug, and found that it was looking for a key inside root/etc/.ssh. My mistake was a running with sudo. If your key is located in home directory - you will get this error.